# How to drop reverse duplicates from a table?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table like this,

Table A:

```
source
  a
  b
  c
  d
```

Table B:

```
destination
    b
    a
    d
    c
```

I have written this query to join two table,

```
with A as(
select row_number() over() idx, source from a 
),
B as (
select row_number() over() idx, destination from b
),
C as (
select A.source, B.destination from A join B on A.idx=B.idx
)

select * from C;
```

This returned this below table,

```
  source  destination
    a        b
    b        a
    c        d
    d        c
```

Now I want to remove reverse duplicates from it. I only want to keep one record a, b not b, a. Similarly I only want c, d not d, c.

Desired Output:

```
source    destination 
  a           b
  c           d
```

Comment: `row_number() over() idx` produces indefinite, random rows ordering. Which may not match your current rows ordering in the output. *This returned this below table* You may obtain another output at any moment.

Comment: @Akina Since I'm not using a groupby or partition. Isn't row_number just returns 1,2 ,3 in sequence for each row? I tried executing my code multiple times and it returns the same output always.

Comment: You need another relation between table a and b.  I think you must add an `id` in table `a` and `a_id` in table `b` like this demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhqJXYFy52xRtVBc97R1EL/3

Comment: It is. But next time it may return the same number to another source row/value - i.e. it may return 1 not for 'a' but for 'd' or another.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Okay I think this is helpful. I'll do that. But Let's say I have both combined then how do I drop the reverse duplicates? Like only keep one instance of the journey?

Comment: and how do we now that b belongs to a and c to d and not a to d, you are missing the point how the system  can identify the rows

Comment: @nbk Assume airport a and airport b. Then airport b to airport a. In these cases how can I drop the duplicates or keep one unique journey point.  I understood that I need a relation between two tables after seeing the comment by Ergest example.

Comment: @Akina Okay. But from my merged table, how can I keep only unique records about source and destination?

Comment: yes you need a bridge table for both so that the system knows which rows belong together and then it gets easy

Comment: check this one https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3df0c910efcb15a709309bcfee8b40d3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from my merged table, how can I keep only unique records about source and destination? – user_12

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM merged_table t1
JOIN merged_table t2 ON t1.src = t2.dst
                    AND t1.dst = t2.src
                    AND t1.src > t2.src;
```

[FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=759b00e49af6cee1cfc4298d2b5aa674) with some explanational queries.

Comment: Can you provide some comments to explain the approach. I didn't get the t1.src > t2.src part?

Comment: @user_12 Without this 3rd condition both pairs (a->b and b->a) matches. Last condition selects only one of this paired rows. Use according SELECT with 2 and with 3 conditions and compare their outputs.

Comment: Okay. I am currently checking it out.

Comment: i still don't see how you will accomplish a merged table

Comment: @nbk OP creates it by some way - I take it as-is. I have already pointed to used method incorrectness.

Comment: @user_12 I add a fiddle - look.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, I only have one doubt, how can strings be compared using `>` (greater than). Is there any docs to read up on these little bit.

Comment: @user_12 Strings can be compared easily. They are compared by symbols, one-by-one, until non-equal symbols meet. The collation is used/applied during symbols compare.